# Yaml ambiguity; indentation spaces and empty node

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

I wrote:

```
a:
-b
-c
```

Parser understood it as:

```
!!map {
  ? !!str "a"
  : !!seq [
      !!str "b",
      !!str "c"
    ]
}
```

But I meant:

```
!!map {
  ? !!str "a"
  : !!null ""
}
!!seq [
  !!str "b",
  !!str "c"
]
```

The specification says:

> The “-”, “?” and “:” characters used
>   to denote block collection entries are
>   perceived by people to be part of the
>   indentation. This is handled on a
>   case-by-case basis by the relevant
>   productions.

So both interpretations are permissible? If not, can you point out section in specification which prevents it?

Depending on "case-by-case basis by the relevant productions" ? What are "relevant productions"?

Comment: What the data structure you expect to get out of the whole document ?

Comment: This question is about percived ambiguity in yaml specification. I expected code labeled "But I meant". If I would add spaces infront of -b and -c, it would parse OK.

Comment: The questions to be answered are: So both interpretations are permissible? If not, can you point out section in specification which prevents it? What are "relevant productions"?

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't parsable by PyYAML 3.11.

http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=a%3A%0A-b%0A-c&type=json

Try this:

```
a:
- b
- c
```

http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=a%3A%0A-+b%0A-+c&type=json

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- a: 
- b
- c
```

```
%YAML 1.1
---
!!seq [
    !!map {
        ? !!str "a"
        : !!null "null",
    },
    !!str "b",
    !!str "c",
]
...
```